# GUI for PHP/MySQL -- Create, Read, Update, Delete

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Looking for a fast, simple way to roll-out a application layer for an existing database. Realize this is a very open end question, so if it is, then the question is what factors should I account for when compare options provided vs. implementation requirements; for example, ORMs supported, js-frameworks supported, etc.

Questions, feedback, comments -- just comment, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/en/)

It is much more light-weight than PhpMyAdmin and IMO provides better interface (though fewer advanced features). And is easier to get rolling - it is only a single PHP file.

I'm not entiery sure what you mean by "ORMs supported". Adminer supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, MS SQL and Oracle database systems, if that's what you mean.

Comment: +1 for simplicity and ease of install

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fewer advanced features"?

Comment: @JakubVrána It simply has more stuff in it, just look at eg. exports , imports and table manipulation tools. Did I miss any of those features in Adminer? No, I would always recommend Adminer over it :) Thanks for a great tool!

Answer (score 4):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)